# How to make getting a pixel value independent of the cv::Mat type?

Tags: c++, opencv, alias

I am writing a method that uses OpenCV (C++).
For example

```
void foo(const cv::Mat &image);
```

Inside, I need to take the pixel value of the `cv::Mat` by row and column.

If the type of image the method works with is `CV_32FC3`, I need to use

```
image.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col);
```

If the type is `CV_32SC2`, I need to use

```
image.at<cv::Vec2i>(row, col);
```

If the type is `CV_8UC1`, I need to use

```
image.at<uchar>(row, col);
```

etc.

I would like the method to be universal, that is, it works with an image with any number of channels and depth. Can anything be done to fulfill this requirement (any template logic)? Perhaps the solution is quite obvious, but I did not find it.

Thank you!

Comment: But how would that work? You need to know the class type of pixel you retrieve. Else you gotta deal with type-erasure techniques that aren't suitable for dealing with something low level as image's pixels.

Comment: Use templated version of mat: `cv::Mat_<TYPE>`, more [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#details). Then one universal function to access pixel is `template<class T> T read(cv::Mat_<T>& image,int r,int c) { return image.at<T>(r,c); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the use of `cv::Mat` - where you have to call `type()` method (at runtime) to get the type of values stored by mat, and instead that just start using templated version of mat class: it is `cv::Mat_<Type>` and write more generic code.

Then you could write only one function template to read mat pixels:

```
template<class T>
T access(cv::Mat_<T> const& img, int r, int c) {
    return img(r,c);
}
```

More about `cv::Mat_` [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#details).

Comment: you should just `return img.at(r,c);`

Comment: Thank you very much!
Tested, it looks like this template version works on all examples.
Now I have to figure out how to embed such a solution in a code where everything is tied to a cv::Mat, but that's another problem. :D